# Conexión a sql server desde otra actividad

Tags: android

Tengo mi MainActivity donde yo ingreso el código de configuración  "204052" y me manda al segundo activity donde ingreso los datos para la conexión a Sql server y hace todo el proceso de conexión y me manda mensaje de conectado. pero lo que quiero hacer es una vez que conecte me mande a mi MainActivity para poder hacer una consulta para validar si el usuario esta dado de alta. 
me pueden ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Quieres pasar de un activity a otro? . Intenta algo asi despues de tu mensaje de "conectado": Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);  startActivity(intent);

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que has realizado. Revisa [ask].